# How to decrypt encoded string created via java code(AES GCM) using javascript crypto.subtle?

Tags: javascript, java, aes-gcm

I am trying to decrypt encoded string in javascript using cryto.subtle. I have encoded this string in java using aes gcm. Please let me know the javascript code(using cryto.subtle) equivalent to below java code. Decryption works in java and just for learning I am using same string as key and initialization vector. Javascript code in giving error while decrypting. I am not using nodejs.

**JAVA code**

```
package com.hm.fcs.controller;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AesGcmExample
{
    static String plainText = "pathname=editOffer&offerId=8ab076727fdbba68017ff98c196b0000&mode=sea";
    public static final int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16;

    // Password derived AES 256 bits secret key
    public static SecretKey getAESKeyFromPassword(char[] password, byte[] salt)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        // iterationCount = 65536
        // keyLength = 256
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
        return secret;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        char[] secretKey = "ZXE-ERW-QDD-EGXL".toCharArray();
        byte[] IV = "ZXE-ERW-QDD-EGXL".getBytes();

//        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
//        random.nextBytes(IV);
        System.out.println("original text : "+plainText);
        SecretKey key = getAESKeyFromPassword(secretKey,IV);
        byte[] cipherText = encrypt(plainText.getBytes(), key, IV);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText));

        String decryptedText = decrypt(cipherText, key, IV);
        System.out.println("DeCrypted Text : " + decryptedText);
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext, SecretKey key, byte[] IV) throws Exception
    {
        // Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        // Create GCMParameterSpec
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8, IV);

        // Initialize Cipher for ENCRYPT_MODE

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, gcmParameterSpec);

        // Perform Encryption
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey key, byte[] IV) throws Exception
    {
        // Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        // Create GCMParameterSpec
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8, IV);

        // Initialize Cipher for DECRYPT_MODE
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, gcmParameterSpec);

        // Perform Decryption
        byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

        return new String(decryptedText);
    }
}
```

**Java script code that I am trying**

```
const pwUtf8 = new TextEncoder().encode("ZXE-ERW-QDD-EGXL");
        console.log("before pwHash");
        const pwHash = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', pwUtf8);
        console.log("after pwHash");
        const ivStr = "ZXE-ERW-QDD-EGXL";
        // iv as Uint8Array
        const iv = new Uint8Array(Array.from(ivStr).map(ch => ch.charCodeAt(0)));

        const alg = { name: 'AES-GCM',
            iv: iv };
        // generate key from pw
        console.log("before key");
        const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', pwHash, alg, false, ['decrypt']);
        console.log("after key");
        const ctStr = "lZSyv0+aBh6x2rSdNwo683Oz0TtJDDzSjsIe7muCm3jHgUoSOacsYP3Qiaocr2oms1uIAA7jOHKFhG1ntcuyqnEe/0Z/6xNj5lyDSvcDpYPNAEeD";
        // ciphertext as Uint8Array


        const ctUint8 = new Uint8Array(Array.from(ctStr).map(ch => ch.charCodeAt(0)));


        try {
            // decrypt ciphertext using key
            console.log("before decrypt");
            const plainBuffer = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(alg, key, ctUint8);
            console.log("after decrypt");
            // return plaintext from ArrayBuffer
            return new TextDecoder().decode(plainBuffer);
        } catch (e) {

            console.log("in catch",e);
        }
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Trying the above javascript code to decrypt but not working. Need equivalent code to java in javascript using crypto.subtle. I am not using nodejs.
Getting this in console
Uncaught (in promise) Error: OperationError

Comment: can you be more precise that "not working"? What does it do? Is there any error? (please include the details in the question itself using the "Edit" link). Note that IMO `throw new Error(error);` in the catch is quite pointless, the point of `try..catch` is to handle the error yourself, by throwing, you just change the place the error is emitted from

Comment: @Kaddath That's totally depends on the requirement whether I want to handle myself or emitted it to some other. Will check further on this. I have added the error that I am getting in console.

Comment: Help us out here. The code could be failing at any of the await style calls - crypto.subtle.digest, crypto.subtle.importKey or crypto.subtle.decrypt . Can you add some console logging before and after the three calls that logs the arguments to the calls.

Comment: You should have a line number in you error, can you tell us which line causes this error? (not just the number, we don't have the full code so it won't help as line numbers won't correspond). @JohnWilliams I think it's not from `crypto.subtle.decrypt` because of the "Uncaught"

Comment: @Kaddath I have added console logs. Those will help and error is coming while await crypto.subtle.decrypt(alg, key, ctUint8).

Comment: What is console.log("in catch",e); writing?

Comment: @JohnWilliams in catch Error

Comment: In the WebCrypto code, the key derivation via PBKDF2 is missing. Also, there seems to be an issue with Base64 decoding. By the way, the reuse of key/IV pairs for GCM is a serious vulnerability.

Comment: @Topaco Can you please share working code equivalent to java